# How to receive all terms of a custom taxonomy with WP REST API v2

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, wordpress-rest-api

Is there any possibility to get all terms of a custom taxonomy with WP REST API v2? When accessing `https://example.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/my-custom-taxonomy` I get only 10 terms.

According to the [documention](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/taxonomies/), there is no way to add a `filter` parameter or something similar (like in the `posts` endpoint).

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the source code, I found out that arguments have to be passed directly as GET argument and not inside a `filter` array.

So `https://example.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/my-custom-taxonomy?per_page=100` works fine.